# Why can't Gible learn Outrage from Tyranitar?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-sixth-generation

Tyranitar can learn Outrage, Gible can learn Outrage, they're both in the monster egg group, so why can Tyranitar pass on Thrash but not Outrage to Gible?

Is there a particular pattern to what moves can be inherited from which parent in Gen VI?

Comment: It... [*should*](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/egg/443.shtml) be able to pass down outrage... only thing I can figure is that each parent can only pass down a single egg-move? And thrash has a priority for some reason?

Comment: Nope, I tried that =( but Bulbapedia seems to back me up on this - http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Gible_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#By_breeding

Comment: Bulbapedia just lists parents that can learn the move naturally for simplicity. Learning an egg-move through a parent who learned it as an egg-move should be/was possible. Getting Tyranitar to forget thrash doesn't work?

Comment: No, I tried that before asking the question. And I'm not sure that's true, because the Horsea family needs breeding to learn Dragon Breath, but Bulbapedia lists them for Gible learning Dragon Breath.

Comment: I know its late, but if you check [this](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Outrage_(move)), Gible cannot learn Outrage from Tyranitar

Comment: As @TrentHawkins mentioned, that just gives a list of parents that learn the move directly. There shouldn't be a limitation on which parents can pass the egg move (as long as they learn the move somehow).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely cause with the information provided: your Tyranitar levelled up enough to automatically forget Outrage in the Day Care, then you retrieved him (by accident?), causing his previous moves to be completely forgotten, then you stored him again, at which point he no longer had Outrage. If you want to make sure the move you're trying to breed down is not lost, do not retreive that Pokémon from the Day Care until you no longer need it.